# Sinatra doesn't know this ditty?

Tags: ios, ruby, command-line, spotify

I am trying to setup the Spotify IOS API but everytime I run this Ruby file and go to `http://localhost:1234/swap` I get "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty".

Here is my code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'base64'
require 'json'
require 'encrypted_strings'

# This is an example token swap service written
# as a Ruby/Sinatra service. This is required by
# the iOS SDK to authenticate a user.
#
# The service requires the Sinatra and
# encrypted_strings gems be installed:
#
# $ gem install sinatra encrypted_strings
#
# To run the service, enter your client ID, client
# secret and client callback URL below and run the
# project.
#
# $ ruby spotify_token_swap.rb
#
# IMPORTANT: The example credentials will work for the
# example apps, you should use your own in your real
# environment. as these might change at any time.
#
# Once the service is running, pass the public URI to
# it (such as http://localhost:1234/swap if you run it
# with default settings on your local machine) to the
# token swap method in the iOS SDK:
#
# NSURL *swapServiceURL = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://localhost:1234/swap"];
#
# -[SPAuth handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL:url
#                   tokenSwapServiceEndpointAtURL:swapServiceURL
#                                        callback:callback];
#

print "\e[31m------------------------------------------------------\e[0m\n"
print "\e[31mYou're using example credentials, please replace these\e[0m\n"
print "\e[31mwith your own and remove this silly warning.\e[0m\n"
print "\e[31m------------------------------------------------------\e[0m\n"
print "\7\7"
sleep(2)

CLIENT_ID = ""
CLIENT_SECRET = ""
ENCRYPTION_SECRET = ""
CLIENT_CALLBACK_URL = "dawgone://returnhere"
AUTH_HEADER = "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET)
SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT = URI.parse("https://accounts.spotify.com")

set :port, 1234 # The port to bind to.
set :bind, '0.0.0.0' # IP address of the interface to listen on (all)


post '/swap' do

    # This call takes a single POST parameter, "code", which
    # it combines with your client ID, secret and callback
    # URL to get an OAuth token from the Spotify Auth Service,
    # which it will pass back to the caller in a JSON payload.

    auth_code = params[:code]

    http = Net::HTTP.new(SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.host, SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/token")

    request.add_field("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER)

    request.form_data = {
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri" => CLIENT_CALLBACK_URL,
        "code" => auth_code
    }

    response = http.request(request)

    # encrypt the refresh token before forwarding to the client
    if response.code.to_i == 200
        token_data = JSON.parse(response.body)
        refresh_token = token_data["refresh_token"]
        encrypted_token = refresh_token.encrypt(:symmetric, :password => ENCRYPTION_SECRET)
        token_data["refresh_token"] = encrypted_token
        response.body = JSON.dump(token_data)
    end

    status response.code.to_i
    return response.body
end

post '/refresh' do

    # Request a new access token using the POST:ed refresh token

    http = Net::HTTP.new(SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.host, SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/token")

    request.add_field("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER)

    encrypted_token = params[:refresh_token]
    refresh_token = encrypted_token.decrypt(:symmetric, :password => ENCRYPTION_SECRET)

    request.form_data = {
        "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token" => refresh_token
    }

    response = http.request(request)

    status response.code.to_i
    return response.body

end
```

Comment: Hi. I work at Spotify. I've noticed that you've pasted your application secret to a public forum. This is a pretty bad idea, and is actually a violation of the Spotify Developer ToS. It'd be a good idea to revoke your current secret and generate a new one. In the future, please be careful and remove secrets from your public posts.

Comment: In response to your comment below, you'll want to look up a tutorial on how to use curl. If you google "How to do HTTP post with curl" you will probably find some good ones. Also consult the spotify API docs and go from there. As iKenndac said, you'll probably want to edit your original post also to remove the secret and generate a new one. Good luck on all your learning!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `swap` is a POST endpoint. When you pull up a URL in your browser you are doing an HTTP `GET`.

If you want to see that the sinatra service is running and you can at least talk to it you could try hitting it with curl from the command line with the right `POST` parameters.

Comment: So what should I do? Sorry I'm not good with ruby I mainly write swift and objective-c

Comment: You shouldn't try to look at the results of the `swap` endpoint in your browser. Look up a good `curl` tutorial - it'll help you learn how to use the tool to help debug and work with web services like this. Since the `swap` endpoint (and most `POST` web APIs) require input data sent in a certain way to work properly, a web browser isn't the correct place to debug like this.